# How to trigger a popup in nextjs with other components?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a modal that I want to use login and register as a component.

In the future, I'm going to implement "favorite" post features for example, which can only be used if the user is logged in, otherwise the popup will skip. Same for different functions + for the login buttons.

That is why I thought that the best thing would be to add this popup to the layout directly if the user is not logged in and to show it if he presses the different buttons.

However, I do not find the solution, how can I trigger and see the modal using different components? Do I have to import it in all the components that are going to trigger the popup? Isn't this going to saturate the app?

este es mi popup actual:

```html
'use client';
import { Dialog, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'

interface ModalBasicProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
  title: string
  isOpen: boolean
  setIsOpen: (value: boolean) => void
}

export default function ModalBasic({
  children,
  title,
  isOpen,
  setIsOpen
}: ModalBasicProps) {
  return (
    <>
    <Transition appear show={isOpen}>
      <Dialog as="div" onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
        <Transition.Child
          className="fixed inset-0 bg-slate-900 bg-opacity-30 z-50 transition-opacity"
          enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
          enterFrom="opacity-0"
          enterTo="opacity-100"
          leave="transition ease-out duration-100"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0"
          aria-hidden="true"
        />
        <Transition.Child
          className="fixed inset-0 z-50 overflow-hidden flex items-center my-4 justify-center px-4 sm:px-6"
          enter="transition ease-in-out duration-200"
          enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4"
          enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
          leave="transition ease-in-out duration-200"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
          leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4"
        >
          <Dialog.Panel className="bg-white rounded shadow-lg overflow-auto max-w-lg w-full max-h-full">
            {/* Modal header */}
            <div className="px-5 py-3 border-b border-slate-200">
              <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
                <Dialog.Title className="font-semibold text-slate-800">{title}</Dialog.Title>
                <button className="text-slate-400 hover:text-slate-500" onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); setIsOpen(false); }}>
                  <div className="sr-only">Close</div>
                  <svg className="w-4 h-4 fill-current">
                    <path d="M7.95 6.536l4.242-4.243a1 1 0 111.415 1.414L9.364 7.95l4.243 4.242a1 1 0 11-1.415 1.415L7.95 9.364l-4.243 4.243a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.415L6.536 7.95 2.293 3.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L7.95 6.536z" />
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            {children}
          </Dialog.Panel>
        </Transition.Child>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition>
    </>
  )
}
```